# Redmine - Project specific development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, project, redmine, redmine-plugins

While modifying redmine,  I stuck on that part:
To hide the menu link "Activity" from a specific project.

My first try was that:
`lib/redmine.rb - Line 239`

> menu.push :activity, { :controller => 'activities', :action => 'index'
>   }, :if => Proc.new { Project.id==1 }

But I guess Project is undefined at the moment when this file is loaded.
Even though there is this nice plugin api. Which got this method: `delete_menu_item`
But how would I tell my plugin something like that:

```
if(Project.id == 1) then delete_menu_item(:project_menu, :activity) end
```

I guess both methods would work. But I can't get them working.
Some (maybe) useful information:

- Redmine version                2.3.2.stable
- Ruby version                   1.9.3-p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails version                  3.2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally have my solution now:

```
menu.push :activity, { :controller => 'activities', :action => 'index' },
    :if => Proc.new {|project| project.id==1 }
```

Thanks to Arnaud Martel for helping me with that.